# Getting contents of indesign text frame through applescript

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

I am trying to form an applescript that will read the contents of one text frame in indesign and if that frame contains a character "/" then it will move another text frame. I figured out how to make the other text frame move, I cannot figure out a way to make applescript "read" what is in the first text frame and search for a character. Here is what I have so far...

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
    tell active document

        set horizontal measurement units of view preferences to inches
        set vertical measurement units of view preferences to inches
        repeat with x from 1 to count pages
            set ThisPage to page x

            tell ThisPage
                if (get text frames whose name of applied object style is "Box1") contains character "/" then
                    move (get text frames whose name of applied object style is "Box2") by {-1.245, 0} --relative move x, y 
                end if
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

I either get no error but it won't do anything or else it gives me compiler errors. Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your "if" test

if  exists (text frames whose (name of applied object style is "Box1" and contents contains "/"))